# Drag-dropping M4R Ringtone to iTunes 12.0.1 to appear in iTunes ringtone folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones, itunes

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/audio/3274143/make-song-your-iphone-ringtone/) for older iTunes but things have apparently changed in iTunes 12.0.1 and iOS 8.1. The drag-dropping and the double-clicking the M4R file do not work anymore. So

**How can I create a ringtone to appear in iPhone and iTunes ringtone folder for iTunes12 and iOS8?**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just tested and the process worked correctly in iTunes 12.0.1. However, I did initially encounter an issue when I tried to add a file that had the same name and was the same size as a song already in my iTunes Library.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I dragged-and-dropped `MyFile.mp3` into iTunes.
2. I right-clicked on it and chose "Create AAC Version".
3. I right-clicked on the AAC version and chose "Show in Finder".
4. I dragged-and-dropped the AAC version onto my desktop, creating a copy.
5. I renamed the file on my desktop to `MyFile.m4r`.
6. I dragged-and-dropped the file back into iTunes. This didn't do anything. However, having read that iTunes sometimes refuses to import files like this, since it thinks they are identical, I removed the AAC version from iTunes.
7. I again dragged-and-dropped the m4r version into iTunes, and this time it showed up in the Tones section of the Library correctly.

Comment: Hurray! I call this an usability bug, it worked like a charm after renaming the file. Thank you +1!

Comment: I don't see "Create AAC Version" in my menu.

Comment: What version of iTunes are you using?

Comment: I cannot understand: firstly changing the length of the ringtone plays only the ringtone length despite you still have the long sound like over 3 minutes like [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6zgqt715v4sx5m/20141207_ringtone.png?dl=0). Secondly after I synced my iPhone with my OSX, the ringtone somehow disappared from my iPhone (new iOS issue?) :/

Comment: There is a maximum length for ringtones, yes. Changing the length of the song above that will have no effect. Changing to length to less than that WILL have an effect though. As far as syncing issues, make sure you have the box checked to sync tones on the iPhone's Tones tab in iTunes when the iPhone is plugged in.

Comment: I was missing "Create AAC Version" as well - you have to go to File > Convert > Create AAC Version